# error: Type mismatch: inferred type is List<String> but MutableList<String> was expected

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to solve the problem below:

Write a method called `parseScript` that accepts a single `String` and returns a `Map<String, MutableList<String>>`. The passed String contains a script consisting of lines separated by newlines, each with the following format:

```
Name: Line
```

For example, here's a simple script:

```
Geoffrey: What do you think of this homework problem?
Ahmed: it's a bit sus
Geoffrey: I bet they'll be able to figure it out!
Maaheen: We'll be here to help if they need it.
```

`parseScript` parses the script and returns a map mapping each character's name to their lines in order. So, for the script above, the map would contain three keys: "Geoffrey", "Ahmed", and "Maaheen". The `List<String>` for the key "Geoffrey" would contain the Strings "What do you think of this homework problem!" and "I bet they'll be able to figure it out!" The `List<String>` for the key "Ahmed" would contain the String "it's a bit sus".

My attempt is:

```
fun parseScript(script: String): Map<String, MutableList<String>> {
    var map = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()
    for (line in script.lines()) {
        var parts = line.split(":")
        var character = parts[0].trim()
        var dialogue = parts[1].trim()
        map[character] = (map[character] ?: mutableListOf<String>()) + dialogue
    }
    return map
}
```

This produces the error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is List<String> but MutableList<String> was expected
```

on the line

```
map[character] = (map[character] ?: mutableListOf<String>()) + dialogue
```

According to my understanding, the elvis operator there should deal with the null issues but I'm not sure why I'm still getting the error.

Can someone please explain why this error is occurring and how to fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

The error here is not about nulls. The error is saying that the map is expecting a `MutableList` as its value, but the expression you wrote after `map[character] =` is:

```
(map[character] ?: mutableListOf<String>()) + dialogue
```

The `+` operator here produces a `List`, not a mutable one.

You can create a new mutable list from the `List` by calling `toMutableList`:

```
((map[character] ?: mutableListOf<String>()) + dialogue).toMutableList()
```

But that is quite unnecessary, since `map[character] ?: mutableListOf<String>()` is already a mutable list already. Why not just add to that?

To do that, use [`getOrPut`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html):

```
map.getOrPut(character, ::mutableListOf).add(dialogue)
```

This tries to get `map[character]`. If it exists, `add(dialogue)` to it. Otherwise, put a new list into the map, as created by `mutableListOf()`. And also `add(dialogue)` to it.

Note that you can do this more declaratively by using [`groupByTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by-to.html):

```
fun parseScript(script: String): Map<String, MutableList<String>> =
    script.lines().map { 
        it.split(":")
    }.groupByTo(
        mutableMapOf(), 
        keySelector = { it[0].trim() },
        valueTransform = { it[1].trim() }
    )
```